# Tacotron2 TTS viseme generation

Tags: text-to-speech

I am currently working on a project that use tacotron2 TTS to produce human like voice for a robot. I would also like to get the visemes from the TTS, so I can synchronize the robot face animation with the voice. How could I get the visemes and the duration of each one with tacotron2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the phonemes out? You can refer to [these](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-polly-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/ref-phoneme-tables-shell.md) phoneme-viseme tables to do conversion. You could try using espeak to do the text -> phoneme conversion. If you don't mind just a rough sync you could compare the duration of espeak output to your tacotron2 output.